# Primeng p-datatable export output different than column result

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using an ng-template in my p-column to transform an ID into a value in some cases, like:

```
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of getColumns()" [field]="col.name" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="true">
      <ng-template let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        {{format(data,col)}}
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Works perfectly on the screen, but when I export the table contents, the column in question exports with the ID not the value. Any clues? I'm using primeng 4.3.0 btw.

Comment: It's not possible right now. All you can do is transform your data in your component before assigning it to your table.

Comment: @Antikhippe - Maybe not an answer, but this allowed me to resolve with a clear conscience. Thanks!